# Expectation and power spectrum density of a stochastic system

Tags: stochastic-processes

I am working on a problem and hoping to receive either  confirmation that my work is correct or guidance on where I am going wrong. The problem is shown below;

[image]

Here is my work;

a)
$$
E\{ X(t) \} = \eta_{_X} (t) = 2 E\{ Z(t) \} + 3 \lambda = 2 \lambda + 3 \lambda = 5 \lambda \\
E\{ Y(t) \} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \eta_{_X} (t - \tau) h(\tau) d\tau = 5 \lambda \int_{0}^\infty  e^{-a \tau} d\tau = \frac{5 \lambda}{a}
$$

where $ E\{ Z(t) \} = \lambda $ is given in the problem statement.

b)

$$
\begin{align}
R_{_{XX}}(\tau) = E\{ X(\tau)^2 \} &= E\{ (2 Z(\tau) + 3 \lambda)^2 \} \\
&=  4 E\{ Z (\tau)^2 \} + 12 \lambda E\{ Z (\tau) \} + 9 \lambda^2 \\
&=  4 R_{_{ZZ}}(\tau) + 12 \lambda E\{ Z (\tau) \} + 9 \lambda^2 \\
&= 4\left( \lambda^2 + \lambda \delta(\tau) \right) + 12 \lambda(\lambda) + 9 \lambda^2 \\
&= 25 \lambda^2 + 4 \lambda \delta(\tau)
\end{align}
$$
where $ R_{_{ZZ}}(\tau) = \lambda^2 + \lambda \delta(\tau) $ is given in the problem statement and  $ \tau = t_2 - t_1 $. Next, we take the Fourier transform of $ R_{_{XX}}(\tau) $ to get the spectral density ($S_{_{XX}}(\omega)$). Additionally, we take the fourier transform of the transfer function $ h(t) $.

$$
S_{_{XX}}(\omega) =  \mathscr{F} \{ R_{_{XX}}(\tau) \} = \mathscr{F} \{ 25 \lambda^2 + 4 \lambda \delta(\tau) \} = 25 \lambda^2 \delta(\omega) + 4 \lambda \\
H(\omega) = \mathscr{F} \{ h(\tau) \} = \mathscr{F} \{ e^{-a \tau} u(\tau) \} = \frac{1}{a + i \omega}
$$

where $i = \sqrt{-1} $. Finally, we obtain the power spectral density of the output ($S_{_{YY}}(\omega)$) as follows;

$$
S_{_{YY}}(\omega) = S_{_{XX}}(\omega)H(\omega)H(-\omega) = \frac{25 \lambda^2 \delta(\omega) + 4 \lambda}{(a + i \omega)(a - i \omega) } = \frac{25 \lambda^2 \delta(\omega) + 4 \lambda}{ a^2 + \omega^2 }
$$

Is this work correct? Any comments/corrections are greatly appreciated.